# Elementor doesn't work properly on Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, elementor, multisite

I've just set up a new multisite network, my original site still works perfectly. However, when I activate Elementor on the new sub-site, it doesn't display correctly and I cannot use it at all.
[Elementor bug 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6T34.png)
[Elementor bug 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBbAV.png)
Additionally, when I've already deactivated the plugin, the admin bar for the website still didn't display properly like this, so I wonder whether it was Elementor's errors or basically Wordpress'
[(admin bar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wenyw.png)

Here is the code in my wp-config and htaccess file

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'thisismysite.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The code Wordpress told me to add has two different lines:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
```

However, if I pasted exactly the original code, I can't even access to the wp-admin of the new sub-site. I have searched on Google and tried to activate/deactivate plugins as well as create a new sub-site but it still didn't work.

Hope you guys could help me solve this error, thank you in advance!!

Update: I have changed to the original code of WP and the site is ok but Elementor still doesn't work while others work fine. Also I still encounter the error with the admin bar

Answer (score 1):

Write your actual domain name in the define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE','') line. I can see that you have now added a dummy domain name.

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'thisismysite.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Also, you have to replace the .htaccess file code with the code that WordPress has given you. You can find that code in tools > Network Setup. Now your multisite will work fine and you can easily use Elementor on it without facing an issue.

Comment: I have changed everything just like you said but it still didn't work

Comment: does multisite is working fine?? means are you able to add a site to it?

Comment: Yes, it is ok, my sub-site displays fine when I view it as guest

Comment: I have rollbacked my Elementor to the previous version and it works fine now. Thank you for your help!